# Creating a link within another link item in HTML page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tags, href

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to create a website.

One of the pages in this website, presents a list of items.

[image: List of items]

In each item box, there is a little `x` to the right, which the user should be able to click to remove the item from the list. Also, clicking in the general area of a list item links to that items unique page.

Please see the JSFiddle I prepared:

[`JSFiddle Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8018/)

**The problem** is that I can't seem to put a link on the `x`. If I try surrounding the `x` with

```
<a href="item2/delete">....</a>
```

the layout falls apart, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8019/).

Since I'm using Bootstrap, I'm stuck with using their lists which are essentially composed of links (i.e. `<a>` tags). Despite this, is there any way I can include links like my `x` inside them?

I've tried using Jquery to create a listener on specifically the `x` but it still doesn't work (clicking the `x` takes you to the link of the item).

Please help!

Comment: Please post your jQuery attempt as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add onclick event handler and prevent the default onclick event which is causing the page to be redirected. Try this, I have added an id to your second 'X' button.

```
$('#linkTo').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/52VtD/8024/)

I guess this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

check the demo, is that are you looking for

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8018/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.glyphicon-remove').on('click',function(){

        return false;
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use relative wrapper + absolute link for close button as follow:

```
<div class='wrap'>
            <a href="/proj/item/1" class="list-group-item"> 
                <img class="" style="float: left; padding-right: 20px;" src="http://www.clinicalflow.com/skins/common/icons/icon-check.gif" />
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">item 1</h4>         
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">Avail. since: 01/01/01</p>
            </a>
                <a hrerf='#' onclick="alert('assign delete link in href');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a>
            </div>  
 <style>
.wrap{
    position:relative;
}
.glyphicon{
    position:absolute;
    right: 50px; top: 30px;
    width: 10px; height:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}  
 </style>
```

`js fiddle sample:` http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8026/